# Taking input an arbitrary number of times

Tags: java, input

I am looking to solve a coding problem, which requires me to take the input an arbitary number of times with one integer at one line. I am using an `ArrayList` to store those values.

---

```
The input will contain several test cases (not more than 10). Each
testcase is a single line with a number n, 0 <= n <= 1 000 000 000.
It is the number written on your coin.
```

---

For example

```
Input:

12
2
3
6 
16
17
```

---

**My attempt to take input in Java:**

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
while(inp.hasNext()){
    list.add(inp.nextInt());
    }
```

---

However, when I try to print the elements of the list to check if I have taken the inputs correctly, I don't get any output. the corresponding correct code in C goes like this:

---

```
unsigned long n;
while(scanf("%lu",&n)>0)
{
   printf("%lu\n",functionName(n));
}
```

---

Please help me fix this thing with Java.

---

*(PS: I am not able to submit solutions in Java because of this )*

Answer (score 3):

You can do this one thing! At the end of the input you can specify some character or string terminator.

**code:**

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
while(inp.hasNextInt())
{
    list.add(inp.nextInt());
}
System.out.println("list contains");
for(Integer i : list)
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

**sample input:**

```
10
20
30
40
53
exit
```

**output:**

```
list contains
10
20
30
40
53
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this:

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(inp.hasNextInt()){
        list.add(inp.nextInt());
    }
```

If there is some another value like character, loop finishes.

Comment: Its very similar to what I did, but it does not work. Like I said, the input format is pre-specified and I cannot ask the user to enter a character or anything like that to indicate the end of input..